# Interceptor before validation.xml

Tags: validation, struts2, interceptor

We know that ActionClassName-validation.xml is executed before ActionClassName.java.

Now I have a interceptor which is executed before the ActionClassName.java.

The order of execution is:

1. ActionClassName-validation.xml
2. Interceptor
3. ActionClassName.java

My question is: Is it possible to have the following order?

1. Interceptor
2. ActionClassName-validation.xml
3. ActionClassName.java

In my struts.xml I have the following configuration:

```
<interceptor class="com.myproject.user.interceptor.PermissionInterceptor"    name="PermissionInterceptor"></interceptor>
<interceptor-stack name="permissionStack">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/> 
    <interceptor-ref name="PermissionInterceptor" />
</interceptor-stack>

<action name="addCommentAction" class="com.myproject.action.AddCommentAction">
    <interceptor-ref name="permissionStack" />
    <result name="success">homePage.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">homePage.jsp</result>          
    <result name="login">login.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">addComment.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Thanks in advance,
Nabil

Comment: So change the order in your interceptor stack. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `struts.xml`

```
<package name="mydefault" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="yourInterceptor" class="YourPackage.YourInterceptorClass"></interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="yourInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-ref name="validationWorkflowStack" />
            .... Other interceptors
        </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>
...Other actions
</package>
```

You can change the order.

For more detailed order See [Interceptor Documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/interceptors.html)

The `defaultStack` interceptor list is as below.

```
<interceptor-stack name="defaultStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="profiling"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
              <param name="excludeParams">dojo\.. * , ^ struts \ .. *</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
```

You can put them in `struts.xml` as below by changing the order.

```
<package name="mydefault" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="yourInterceptor" class="YourPackage.YourInterceptorClass"></interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="servletConfig"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="prepare"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="i18n"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="chain"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="debugging"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="profiling"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="scopedModelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="modelDriven"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="checkbox"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="staticParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="actionMappingParams"/>
            <interceptor-ref name="params">
                  <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="conversionError"/>

            /*putting your interceptor in between or any order */                
            <interceptor-ref name="yourInterceptor" />

            <interceptor-ref name="validation">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
                <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="paramsPrepareParamsStack" />

            <interceptor-ref name="validationWorkflowStack" />
            .... Other interceptors
        </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>
<default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>
...Other actions
</package>
```